# How to find a particular string in a clob which has another string as prefix to it

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me illustrate what I need with an example.

Suppose my table has two columns, the first column is the primary key and the second column is a CLOB.

Suppose the clob column in my table holds the following data:

```
Method_name : Test_method_124

Grading: As Specified

Grading Time Period: 2016 Fall
```

I want to find the string which is after 'Grading Time Period'. The output of my query should be the primary key (that is, the first column of the table) and '2016 Fall'

Comment: 1) In the clob, what is the primary key? 2) Where is this clob stored and how and where do you want to store primary key and clob again?

Comment: Share reproducible example so that we can figure out the pattern in second column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DBMS_LOB functions to work with CLOBs.  `instr()` returns the starting offset of the searched pattern in a CLOB. `substr()` returns a substring, which is *n* characters from the given offset in a CLOB. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600)

```
SQL> select id,
  2        dbms_lob.substr(txt, 30, dbms_lob.instr(txt,'Grading Time Period')+21) as snippet
  3  from t23
  4  where dbms_lob.instr(txt, 'Grading Time Period') > 0:

        ID SNIPPET
---------- ----------
         1 2016 Fall

SQL>
```

This is a poor way to store data. Really this should be properly normalised into table columns. But even XML or JSON would be a better way of handling this. Look at it this way. If you wanted to extract the `Grading` how would you specify the buffer to ensure you grabbed only `As Specified`? It's possible but it's gnarly.